# Magnetic strength of an electron

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Analogy: when you go to a store to buy a magnet - it usually has a note about how much weight it can on average support.

So, since charged particles are "tiny magnets" - is there some similar measure (or even measures) for just 1 particle?

Do these measures depend on a speed of a charged particle? What else do they depend on?

..Also, it surely depends on how many electrons have their spins aligned in the same direction (as they do in actual magnets, making their microscopic properties visible on our level of existence). Therefore, *too much* QED is going on here, obviously.

But I'm asking anyways.

Comment: Check out this link :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton

Answer (score 1):

That measure in pounds is probably according to some metallic standard "LBs of stainless steel" for example. A strong magnet probably couldn't pick up much lead or copper, but quite a bit of a heavier quantity of iron. Steel has a density of permanent magnetic dipoles as well as a mass density. The magnet's field acts on the dipoles and there's a ratio of dipoles to weight. So in that sense the strength of the magnet is proportional to pounds it can lift. That weight though is ultimately a result of the magnet's Field which can be measured in Teslas or Gauss.

Ultimately, the strength of a magnet is due to its strength and vector sum of its magnetic moments.

A semi-classical approach is possible.

$\mu=IA=\frac{e v}{2\pi R}\pi R^2=\frac{evRm_e}{2m_e}=\frac{e\hbar}{4m_e}$

We approximate the electron as a current loop. The current is charge times velocity divided by length of the loop. Area is area of the loop. The $m_evR$ is the angular momentum, intrinsically $\hbar/2$ for an electron.

For some reason I'm off by a factor of 2 from the real value of the Bohr Magneton, $\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}$.

$\frac{\mu_0I}{2R}\hat{k}$ = magnetic field at center of a current loop. So, roughly, the field due to a moment is the moment divided by area times $\mu_0/2R$

$\frac{\mu_0}{2R}\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\approx B$.

$R=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0m_ec^2}$ is the classical radius of the electron, on the other hand $\hbar/m_ec$, the reduced Compton Wavelength of the Electron might be more appropriate.

Swap in appropriate values, should get you in the ball park of the field strength. You probably want to express that as a ratio of some index magnetic field. For example, Earth's is 0.5 G.

Comment: I was personally more interested in QED approach, not classical; despite the fact that I can't read the math right ahead. But that is helpful anyway, thank you!